# Postgres 9.4 to 9.5 using Yum and pg_upgrade - CentOS 6.7 (Final)

Tags: postgresql-9.4, upgrade, centos, postgresql-9.5

I am attempting to do an upgrade between Postgres 9.4 to 9.5 on a CentOS 6.7 system.

I have reviewed both:
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pgupgrade.html

My only concern is data corruption and loss, after some searching it seems that others are having issues during such an upgrade. I was hoping someone with some more experience performing version upgrades with Postgres could provide some insight on the best approach and what I should be concerned about during the upgrade.